# How can I find my units in Civilization 5?

Tags: civilization-5

I often want to find a specific unit. For example: maybe I want to bring an Exploring ship back to port, or find artillery to help with a siege.

In Civ 4 I could go to the military adviser screen and see an awesome map, filterable by player and by unit type, showing the location of every individual unit my civilization was aware of.

Civ 5's "Military Overview" (F3) is a pale shadow of that. Among other things, while I can see which units exist and what they're doing, I can't seem to find where they are.

Am I missing something? Short of that, I'd be happy just for something that let me cycle through all the units, but all I've found is a way to cycle through all units that are awaiting orders—useless if a unit is exploring, fortified, or asleep.

Comment: I do not play Civ 5, but it seems to be missing a lot of nice features from 4! Hopefully there is a big patch or something in the pipes for everyone!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the unit overview (selectable from the top-left button), you can either double-click a unit - to select it and center your view on it - or you can click a unit and then, in the lower-left unit info box, either click its portrait or its name.

As far as I know there is no way to get an immediate overview of where all your units are, which is a shame - I would also be interested in something like that. They don't even appear in the mini-map in any form until after you select them...

You can find more information about the unit list (for example, what do the colors mean) in [my answer to another question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8245/understanding-unit-movement/8248#8248).

Comment: Bingo, thanks. Much as I'd like to have it, I can live without the global unit view.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the new strategic view.  Among the many overlays available for it is one that shows an icon for each unit (for ease of use, you might want to disable the other icons and overlays), and you can easily scroll out far enough to see your entire empire.  I believe you can even control your units directly from that view.